# OSGi/Equinox: How do I convert a resource URI into a bundle name?

Tags: url, classpath, osgi, equinox

After looking up a resource on the classpath, I got this URL:

```
bundleresource://23.fwk1186515174/com/google/inject/Injector.class
```

How can I find out in which bundle provided the resource?

**[EDIT]** I'm trying to debug a problem where I have duplicate classes on the classpath. Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void debugClassPath() {
    String resource = "com/google/inject/Injector.class";
    try {
        Enumeration<URL> urls = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources( resource );

        while( urls.hasMoreElements() ) {
            System.out.println(urls.nextElement());
        }

        System.out.println("---");

        urls = XtextRunner.class.getClassLoader().getResources( resource );

        while( urls.hasMoreElements() ) {
            System.out.println(urls.nextElement());
        }
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That gives me several URLs for `com.google.inject.Injector` and I want to figure out which bundles add them to the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSGi urls guarantee the hierarchy. So just replace `com/google/inject/Injector.class` with `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and read the resource as a manifest (or text file). The information in there tells you which bundle you're looking at.

Duplicate classes can ONLY happen with split packages which is considered bad (very bad imho) practice. In OSGi, split packages require `Require-Bundle` with re-export or `Bundle-Classpath`. Life is a lot easier without these ...

Comment: Do you have a document which explains what "split packages" are and how to "fix" them? Background: I need enough information/understanding of the issue to tell the projects which are involved how to fix the issue.

Comment: Start using bnd(tools) ... bnd verifiers and yells at you when you have split packages. Split packages are multiple providers for the same package. In OSGi this can only happen when you use Require-Bundle with re-export. Stop doing that and your problems are over.

Split packages are discussed in the specification in the module layer.

Comment: I'm not doing it; it must be in two other projects, so I need to persuade those two to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way is to parse the URL, but this will only work when running on Equinox. According to the source for [BundleResourceHandler](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse/osgi/3.7.0/org/eclipse/osgi/framework/internal/core/BundleResourceHandler.java/?v=source) , that integer ('23') to the right of the URL scheme is the bundle ID. If you have a BundleContext (check your Activator) then you can find which bundle this is with that ID using [getBundle(long)](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r2/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getBundle%28long%29).

There's likely to be a much better way of doing this however. How do you look up the resource on the classpath?

Comment: The usual way: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResources('com/google/inject/Injector.class')`. I'm trying to debug a class loading issue where I get *two* URLs for this resource and I want to know which bundles provide them.

Comment: Presumably one bundle loads one version of the class and another loads a different version? You could try increasing the logging in the Equinox container to see the class loading wiring that is used. Create a .options file as described under 'osgi.debug' in http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html and include 'org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/wiring = true' (there are other options)

Comment: I think that two dependencies of my bundle export the same class but I need to know which ones.

Comment: Well the logging should show how the bundles get wired together.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. However, for Equinox, there is an implementation specific way (subject to change in future releases because it is an implementation specific way) by seeing how the URL handler encodes it in the authority.

Comment: This is Equinox/Eclipse specific. How can I do it in Equinox?